# My calculation function won't work properly -- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sum, calculation, cumulative-sum

I'm currently working on a school project: I had to code a website that sells sofas. I made the whole site but I struggle with my calculation function that adds all the prices of each sofa to get the sum of my cart. It's always false whatever I do. I'm lost.

I had to fetch the prices of the products in my cart from the API and the products from the local storage. Then, I try to calculate the sum of all the prices within a specific function. I tried a loop but the result is always false.

Eg: When I add 2 sofas that cost 4499€ and one sofa of 1849€, the result is 5547 € instead of 10487€.

Getting sofas from LocalStorage : product name, photo and color only

```js
function getCart() {
  let cart = localStorage‧getItem("cart");
  if (cart === null || cart === "[]") {
    let emptyCart = document‧querySelector("#cart__items");
    emptyCart‧innerText = "Votre panier est vide";
    document‧querySelector(".cart__order").style‧display = "none";
    return [];
  } else {
    return JSON‧parse(cart);
  }
}
```

Getting prices from API then adding display functions that need it

```js
async function getPriceFromApi(article) {
  let dataFetch = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/products/${article.id}`
  )
    .then((products) => products‧json())
    .then((product) => {
      return product;
    });

  const apiProduct = {
    price: dataFetch‧price,
  };

  const completeItem = {
    ...article,
    ...apiProduct,
  };

  productDisplay(completeItem);
  displayTotalPrice(apiProduct);
}
```

Calculation : the total price of the cart

```js
function totalPriceCalculation(product) {
  let cart = getCart();
  let total = [];

  cart‧forEach((sumPrice) => {
    let number = eval(sumPrice‧quantity);
    total‧push(product‧price * number);
    console‧log(number, total);
  });
  let totalPrice = `${eval(total‧join("+"))}`;
  return totalPrice;
}
```

Displaying the whole cart (articles + prices) with every display and logic functions :

```js
function completeCart() {
  let cart = getCart();
  displayTotalQuantity();

  cart‧forEach((item) => {
    getPriceFromApi(item);
  });
}

completeCart();
```

My display total price function :

```js
function displayTotalPrice(product) {
  const TotalPrice = document‧querySelector("#totalPrice");
  TotalPrice‧innerText = totalPriceCalculation(product);
  return TotalPrice;
}
```

other functions :
// THE main container

```js
function container(DisplayArticle) {
  document‧querySelector("#cart__items").appendChild(DisplayArticle);
}
```

Here, I gather my query selectors for the images and desctiptions as well as my logic ("settings"= delete and modify) :

```js
// The display function
function productDisplay(product) {
  const DisplayArticle = displayArticle(product);
  container(DisplayArticle);


// functions for the DOM : Query Selectors for HTML elements
  const DisplayImage = displayImage(product); 
  const DisplayDescription = displayDescription(product);

//functions "delete" and "modify quantities"
  const DisplaySettings = settings(product);

  DisplayArticle‧appendChild(DisplayImage);
  DisplayArticle‧appendChild(DisplayDescription);
  DisplayArticle‧appendChild(DisplaySettings);

  return DisplayArticle;
}
```

// Displaing all the articles (it works fine)

```js
function displayTotalQuantity() {
  const AllItems = document‧querySelector("#totalQuantity");
  AllItems‧innerText = totalquantityCalculation();

  return AllItems;
}

function totalquantityCalculation() {
  let cart = getCart();
  let number = 0;

  cart‧forEach((sumItem) => {
    number += eval(sumItem‧quantity);
  });

  return number;
}
``
```

Comment: can you specify a sample for the returned value of `getCart()` function?

Comment: Could you give an example of product you passed to your function, as well as the expected and calculated result ? Generally I am not sure why you use an array for total. You could just do total = 0, then instead of your push, you'd do total = total + price*number, and then just return total.

Comment: I'll answer both of you if you're okay :

The getCart() function is array that contains the products saved in the local storage (each product is an object).

The "product" argument represents those articles with the prices.

Comment: As for the results I get :
For example, I got 2 sofa that cost 1849€ each and one of 4499€. The result I get is either 5547 or 13497 instead of 8197€.

Because Yes, to add insult to injury, I get two different results when I refresh my page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing first, IMO it's better that BE do the calculation..

but yeah try this:

1. `getPriceFromApi` should just return price
2. should just gather data from localstorage `getCart` once in `completeCart`, hence `totalquantityCalculation` & `totalPriceCalculation` will receive `cart` params
3. `totalPriceCalculation` will call `getPriceFromApi` on each product, hence it will be a promise which should call with `await`
4. seperate `totalPriceCalculation` & `totalquantityCalculation` with `displayTotalPrice` & `displayTotalQuantity`, easier to read that

```js
async function getPriceFromApi(product) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/product/${product.id}`
    );
    const dataFetch = await response.json();

    const completeItem = {
      ...article,
      ...dataFetch,
    };
    // not sure about this function
    productDisplay(completeItem);

    return dataFetch.price;
  } catch (e) {
    // do something when got error
  }
}
```

```js
function displayTotalPrice(num) {
  const TotalPrice = document.querySelector('#totalPrice');
  TotalPrice.innerText = num;
}

function displayTotalQuantity(num) {
  const AllItems = document.querySelector('#totalQuantity');
  AllItems.innerText = num;
}

function totalquantityCalculation(cart) {
  let total = 0;
  cart.forEach((product) => {
    total += Number(product.quantity);
  });
  return total;
}

async function totalPriceCalculation(cart) {
  let totalPrice = 0;
  for (const product of cart) {
    const price = await getPriceFromApi(product);
    totalPrice += Number(price) * Number(product.quantity);
  }
  return totalPrice;
}
```

```js
async function completeCart() {
  let cart = getCart();

  const totalQuantity = totalquantityCalculation(cart);
  displayTotalQuantity(totalQuantity);

  const totalPrice = await totalPriceCalculation(cart);
  displayTotalPrice(totalPrice);
}

completeCart();
```

Comment: Thank you ! The first part works but my calculation is still wrong. I think I have to rewrite my whole page but I have no time left. I failed

Comment: ok, can you give more context about this calculation, like:
- what is the data from localstorage?
- what is the response of product api?
- include these data on the question

Comment: Ok let's do that

Comment: @Emy can you also include function `displayTotalQuantity`, `productDisplay`? and I believe there's `product id` on the localstorage data, right?

Comment: I edited my post. 
And yes, it is.

Comment: @Emy my answer's updated

Comment: @Emy happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)